# MYSQL IF Statement reorder by category

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have been attempting to reorder a table in a database based on category and order id for a menu structure.

This is what I have roughly as a table structure

```
menuid menuname      order categoryid
--------------------------------------
1      firstitem       1      1
2      seconditem      2      1
3      thirditem       1      2
4      fourthitem      2      2
```

I have tried this syntax:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET id=IF(id=2, 3, 2) where id in(2,3)
```

like this:

```
UPDATE menu
SET order = IF(order = `3`, `2`, `3`)
WHERE order = `3`
```

I am getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
 MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order = IF(order = `3`, `2`, `3`)
 WHERE order = `3`' at line 2
```

Solution code:

```
UPDATE menu
SET `order` = case when `order` = 3 then 2 else 3 end
WHERE `order` = 3 AND section = 2 OR `order` = 2 AND section = 2
```

Comment: What's with all the backticks? You should't quote values with name qualifiers. They are numeric they can be unquoted or quoted with apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
UPDATE menu
SET `order` = case when `order` = 3 
                   then 2 
                   else `order` 
              end
```

By the way `order` is a reserved word in MySQL. You have to escape it with backticks

Comment: When you use WHERE condition, the CASE is not needed :)

Comment: i hate that feature about `order`

Comment: Then your orignal statement will work if you put order in singlw quotes

Comment: fixed it now with help from you and other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use CASE expression. Your WHERE has no meaning

```
UPDATE menu 
SET order = case when order = `3` then `2` else `3` end
```